# Postgres aggregate function for selecting best / first element in a group

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table of elements with a number of items that need de-duping based on a priority. The following is a grossly simplified but representative example:

```
sophia=> select * from numbers order by value, priority;
 value | priority | label 
-------+----------+-------
     1 |        1 | One
     1 |        2 | Eins
     2 |        1 | Two
     2 |        2 | Zwei
     3 |        2 | Drei
     4 |        1 | Four
     4 |        2 | Vier
(7 rows)
```

I want to restrict this to returning only a single row per number. Easy enough, I can use the first() aggregate function detailed in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)

```
sophia=> select value, first(label) from numbers group by value order by value;
 value | first 
-------+-------
     1 | One
     2 | Two
     3 | Drei
     4 | Four
(4 rows)

sophia=>
```

The problem with this is that the order isn't well defined so if the DB rows were inserted in a different order, I might get this:

```
sophia=> select value, first(label) from numbers group by value order by value;
 value | first 
-------+-------
     1 | Eins
     2 | Zwei
     3 | Drei
     4 | Vier
(4 rows)
```

Of course, the solution to that also seems simple, in that I could just do an order by:

```
sophia=> select value, first(label) from (select * from numbers order by priority) foo group by value order by value;
 value | first 
-------+-------
     1 | One
     2 | Two
     3 | Drei
     4 | Four
(4 rows)

sophia=>
```

However, the problem here is that the query optimizer is free to discard the order by rules in subqueries meaning that this doesn't always work and breaks in random nasty places.

I have a solution that I'm currently using in a handful of places that relies on array_agg.

```
sophia=> select value, (array_agg(label order by priority))[1] as best_label from numbers group by value;
 value | best_label 
-------+------------
     1 | One
     2 | Two
     3 | Drei
     4 | Four
(4 rows)

sophia=>
```

This provides robust ordering but involves creating a bunch of extra arrays during query time that just get thrown away and hence the performance on larger datasets rather sucks.

So the question is, is there a better, cleaner, faster way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last attempt includes the answer to your question, you just didn't realise it:

```
array_agg(label order by priority)
```

Note the `order by` clause *inside* the aggregate function. This isn't special to `array_agg`, but is a general part of [the syntax for using aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

> Ordinarily, the input rows are fed to the aggregate function in an unspecified order. In many cases this does not matter; for example, min produces the same result no matter what order it receives the inputs in. However, some aggregate functions (such as array_agg and string_agg) produce results that depend on the ordering of the input rows. When using such an aggregate, the optional order_by_clause can be used to specify the desired ordering. The order_by_clause has the same syntax as for a query-level ORDER BY clause, as described in Section 7.5, except that its expressions are always just expressions and cannot be output-column names or numbers.

Thus the solution to your problem is simply to put an `order by` inside your `first` aggregate expression:

```
select value, first(label order by priority) from numbers group by value order by value;
```

Given how elegant this is, I'm surprised that `first` and `last` are still not implemented as built-in aggregates.

Answer (score 1):

The Postgres select statement has a clause called DISTINCT ON which is extremely useful in the case when you would like to return one of a group.  In this case, you would use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (value) value, label
FROM numbers
ORDER BY value, priority;
```

Using DISTINCT ON is generally faster than other methods involving groups or window functions.